# Can a list of type<string> containing @Html.ActionLinks be passed as the Model from a Controller to a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that builds Html from a database and stores each html sequence as a string in a list of strings. This list of strings is passed to a View as its model. A Razor foreach loop outputs the Html in the View as follows:

```
@{

    foreach (var Line in Model)
    {
        var myHTML = new HtmlString(@Line);
        @myHTML
    }

 }
```

This logic produces valid hyperlinks for < a href=”URL” > Go To URL < /a> type Html commands.

I have attempted to create @Html.ActionLinks using this paradigm but the Razor code loop interprets @Html.ActionLink  as text, not as a command with a hyperlink. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is the Index() Action used to test:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        List<string> HTMLList = new List<string>();
        string workURL;
        string work;
        workURL = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        work = "<a href=\"" + workURL + "\">" + "This will Work" + "</a>" ;

        HTMLList.Add(work);
        HTMLList.Add("<br/><br/>");

        work = "@Html.ActionLink(\"This Will Be Text not a hyperlink\",\"Display\",\"PDF\")";
        HTMLList.Add(work);
        //HTMLList.Add(work2.HtmlEncode());

        return View("Jay",HTMLList);
    }
```

Here is the View file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Jay";
}

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Jay</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav>
@{ 
    foreach (var Line in Model)
   {
       var myHTML = new HtmlString(@Line);
          @myHTML 
    }
}
    <br />
    </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You probably should be able to use the `UrlHelper` in the servr when you build the string content.

Comment: Could you show us your code that used `@Html.ActionLinks`?

Comment: Richard, as per your request, I added the Index() Action and the View file.

Comment: The Razor view engine will interpret the ActionLink code during run-time while stuffing it as part of a C# string will be interpreted during compile time.